# Prove or disprove: there exists an integer $n$ such that $n^2 \equiv 2 \mod 3$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

I'm having trouble with a homework problem due later today. I need to either prove or disprove the statement  $$n^2 \equiv 2 \mod 3$$

I know that this can be written as $ n^2 = 3k + 2$, where $k \in \mathbb Z$.

I haven't been able to think of any examples, but neither do I know how to disprove this. Can anyone give me a hint on where to go from here?

Comment: Try $n = 3k \pm 1$, always $\equiv 1 \mod{3}$

Answer (score 4):

For such a small modulus, we can simply check all the cases

\begin{align}0^2&\equiv 0\mod 3\\
1^2 &\equiv 1\mod 3\\
2^2 &\equiv 4\mod 3\equiv 1\mod 3\end{align}

Now we can see that $n^2 \not\equiv 2\mod 3$ in any case so there is no solution

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but why do we only need to check when n= 1,2, or 3?

Comment: Because the integers modulo $3$ contain only three elements: $1,2,3$.

Comment: Wow I'm an idiot. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: You can also use: $$n=3k, n^2 = 3(3k^2) \\ n=3k+1, n^2=3(3k^2+2k)+1 \\ n=3k+2, n^2=3(3k^2+4k+1)+1$$ as the three cases to get the same result.